# Boostrap @media print, can I print a desktop version? override xs?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, less, media-queries

I have tried all the possibilities that I have read and doesn´t work.
I want to print a HTML using Bootstrap like Desktop version (not xs media query).

Is it possible?

In my code I have for xs one column hidden but I would like to print all the table.

**index.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped printable">
        <tr>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>    
</table>
```

**theme.less**

```
.printable
{
  color: red;
  margin-top:40px;
  tr{
    td{
      color:blue;
      .make-xs-column(6);
      .make-sm-column(4);
      .make-md-column(8);
      .make-lg-column(8);
      .visible-xs();
      .visible-sm();
      .visible-md();
      .visible-lg();
    }
    td + td{
      color:green;
      .make-sm-column(4);
      .make-md-column(2);
      .make-lg-column(2);
      .hidden-xs();
      .visible-sm();
      .visible-md();
      .visible-lg();
    }
    td + td + td
    {
      color:orange;
      .make-xs-column(6);
      .make-sm-column(4);
      .make-md-column(2);
      .make-lg-column(2);
      .visible-xs();
      .visible-sm();
      .visible-md();
      .visible-lg();
    }
  }
}
```

**print.less**

```
.container {
        max-width: none!important;
        width: 100%!important;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
    .row {
        margin-left: -1%;
        margin-left: -1%;
    }
    [class*="col-"] {
        float: left;
        padding-left: 1%;
        padding-right: 1%;
    }
    .col-xs-12,
    .col-sm-12,
    .col-md-12,
    .col-lg-12 {
        width: 100%
    }
    .col-xs-11,
    .col-sm-11,
    .col-md-11,
    .col-lg-11 {
        width: 91.66666667%
    }
    .col-xs-10,
    .col-sm-10,
    .col-md-10,
    .col-lg-10 {
        width: 83.33333333%
    }
    .col-xs-9,
    .col-sm-9,
    .col-md-9,
    .col-lg-9 {
        width: 75%
    }
    .col-xs-8,
    .col-sm-8,
    .col-md-8,
    .col-lg-8 {
        width: 66.66666667%
    }
    .col-xs-7,
    .col-sm-7,
    .col-md-7,
    .col-lg-7 {
        width: 58.33333333%
    }
    .col-xs-6,
    .col-sm-6,
    .col-md-6,
    .col-lg-6 {
        width: 50%
    }
    .col-xs-5,
    .col-sm-5,
    .col-md-5,
    .col-lg-5 {
        width: 41.66666667%
    }
    .col-xs-4,
    .col-sm-4,
    .col-md-4,
    .col-lg-4 {
        width: 33.33333333%
    }
    .col-xs-3,
    .col-sm-3,
    .col-md-3,
    .col-lg-3 {
        width: 25%
    }
    .col-xs-2,
    .col-sm-2,
    .col-md-2,
    .col-lg-2 {
        width: 16.66666667%
    }
    .col-xs-1,
    .col-sm-1,
    .col-md-1,
    .col-lg-1 {
        width: 8.33333333%
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@media print { 
  .printable {
    tr {
      td + td {
        .visible-xs();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I tried this and doesn´t work, and .visible-print-block(), and the same. I don´t know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

About -

> print a HTML using Bootstrap like Desktop version (not xs media
>   query).

You can Overrid bootstrap XS for each column size you want - only for printing.

Add to your last css file -

If you for example that column that xs-12 would be half like md-6 then add

```
@media print {
    .col-xs-12 {
        width: 50% !important;
    }
}
```

Hope i helped.